# How to pass objects between Pages in Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have my main page and in this page I have a list with objects. With a foreach I get the items of it and I want to pass the item to another page if you click the button. How can I pass it?

Comment: Do a bit of searching for Blazor Application State - [This is a good introduction](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-state-management/). There are many ways to handle state in Blazor - you can choose which way suits your project.

Comment: As your question is a bit thin on code, I would suggest you need to use a scoped service to hold a collection of the objects, probably an `IDictionary` with an integer key you pass to the new page - *newpage/1*.  NewPage  then uses *1* to retrieve the specific object. from the service.  See the MSDocs about services - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

Comment: The easiest answer is-- don't navigate.  I recommend only navigating to move to a separate section of the app (i.e. which doesn't need to pass any data).  Show a control that displays your item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a simple value (`int`, `string`) then you could just pass this value as a path- or query param to the other page:

From page:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/page/a">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="/page/b">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="/page/c">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

to page:

```cs
@page "/page/{PathParam}"

<h1>Page @this.PathParam</h1>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public string PathParam { get; set; }
}
```

However, if the data is more complex, try using one of the options described in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly (*Server-side storage*, *Browser storage* or *In-memory state container service*)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I used a ID from my object so I can use it on the other page.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding more complex objects it is good to use `StateContainer` (in memory solution).

Register your `StateContainer` in `MauiProgram.cs` like:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<StateContainer>();
```

where `StateContainer.cs` contains:

```
public readonly Dictionary<int, object> ObjectTunnel = new();
```

then just as an example I will create `ComplexObject.cs` where

```
public class ComplexObject
{
    public int Count = 0;
    public string Color = string.Empty;
}
```

then when you have pages e.g. `Index.razor` and `Counter.razor` and you would like to send `ComplexObject` from one the the other, then in `Index.razor` inject `StateContainer`

and call something like:

```
public void OpenCounterWithData()
{
    var data = new ComplexObject{Count = 3, Color="red"}
    _stateContainer.ObjectTunnel.Add(data.GetHashCode(), data)

    _navigationManager.Navigate($"counter/{data.GetHashCode()}")
}
```

and In `Counter.razor` you specify page like:

```
@page "/counter/{SetHashCode:int}"
```

and Input parameter:

```
[Parameter] public int SetHashCode { get; set; }
```

and e.g. in `OnInitialized` you can extract the value from `StateContainer` like:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var data = (ComplexObject) _stateContainer.ObjectTunnel[SetHashCode];
}
```

after that you should also remove the object from the `ObjectTunnel`.
This is basically the whole flow.

---

**Optimizations:**

- I have created a few extension methods to optimize the flow

`StateContainerExtensions.cs`

```
public static class StateContainerExtensions
{
    public static int AddRoutingObjectParameter(this StateContainer stateContainer, object value)
    {
        stateContainer.ObjectTunnel[value.GetHashCode()] = value;
        return value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static T GetRoutingObjectParameter<T>(this StateContainer stateContainer, int hashCode)
    {
        return (T) stateContainer.ObjectTunnel.PopValue(hashCode);
    }
}
```

and `DictionaryExtensions.cs`

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue PopValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey keyName) where TKey : notnull
    {
        var value = dictionary[keyName];
        dictionary.Remove(keyName);
        return value;
    }
}
```

With those extension methods you can instead

```
_stateContainer.ObjectTunnel.Add(data.GetHashCode(), data)
```

use just:

```
_stateContainer.AddRoutingObjectParameter(_trainingSet);
```

and instead:

```
var data = (ComplexObject) _stateContainer.ObjectTunnel[SetHashCode];
_stateContainer.ObjectTunnel.Remove(SetHashCode);
```

use:

```
var data = _stateContainer.GetRoutingObjectParameter<ComplexObject>(SetHashCode);
```

Comment: You sir is da real MVP, this solution is an absolute magnificence.

Comment: I think StateContainer must be Scoped instead of the Singleton. I tried Scoped and it works for me. Singleton may cause memory overflow

Comment: @RamilAliyev007 Yes and No. The type of Blazor (Server vs WASM) matters. Because in WASM Singleton=Scoped. In case of Blazor server making it scoped is the right way to do so the state container is used per user/circuit and not across all users. 

Thank you for the heads up.